# Product integral of polynomials

Tags: integration, polynomials, indefinite-integrals

How can we go about finding the Indefinite product integral of polynomials in closed form?

The goal is to some how find the [Product integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral) of a polynomial including the polynomial's constant term. There are some constraint to the input.

- The range the of input polynomial will be greater than 0.001 except for its end behavior.
- The Polynomial is very large, up to $ ax^{512} $

I tried taking the this approach by integrating the natural log of the function and raising $e$ to the output,
$ 
{\displaystyle \lim _{\Delta x\to 0}\prod {f(x_{i})^{\Delta x}}=\exp \left(\int _{0}^{x}\ln f(5x^3+x^2 ...)\,dx\right),}
$
but I could not find a closed form solution when there was a constant term.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. The question is unclear. What does "inefinite product integral? mean? If you [edit] the question to show us a particular integral you want to compute and why some usual technique is unsatisfactory we may be able to help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.